# outputting taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms, hierarchical

I have a site where I've listed a list of subcategories for a side navigation. I need to break those subcategories into a more specific hierarchy. It's currently outputting a list from a parent category but it doesn't display the hierarchy beyond that. I'm kind of stuck at the next step.

This is what I have right now:

```
  foreach($subcategory as $key => $val) {
    $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'post_type' => 'storefront',
     'hierarchical' => true, 
     'child_of' => $parent->term_id,
     'post_status' => array('publish', 'private'),
     'taxonomy' => 'sfcategory',
     'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'sfcategory',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $val,
        'child_of' => $parent->term_id
        )
      )
     );              
    $countStorefront = get_posts($args);
    $count = count($countStorefront);

    if($count) {

   $html .= "<li><a href='".site_url('community?subcat=').$val."'>".$key."</a></li>";

    } else {
      $html .= "<li>".$key."</li>";
    }
  }
  $html .= "</div>";
```

Comment: Is there really a need to display empty terms as list items without links?

Comment: Not in the end result. That's just something someone entering content asked to have in there so they could see something while we're loading categories. I should have just left that out of this example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if the empty terms shouldn't be displayed in there, then it'll be pretty easy ;)

All you have to do is to use [`wp_list_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) function:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        wp_list_categories( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sfcategory',
            'title_li' => false,
            'hide_empty' => true // or false, as you wish
        ) );
    ?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually including this in a shortcode that goes on a page. I'm working behind another developer who is no longer around and I actually need the output of "community?subcat=" to do something else. When I use wp_list_categories it produces of friendly URL that doesn't have any parameters.

Also, wp_list_categories is displaying it like:

- category 1
  - subcategory a
       - subcategory a1
  - subcategory b

- category 2
  - subcategory a

Assuming I'm in category 1, I JUST need category 1 subs to display. I can't figure out how to get wp_list_categories to do that.